# How can I remove the "Eject" icon from the menubar?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, eject

How can i remove the "Eject" icon from the menubar?

It's an icon that starts on login.
It ejects all mounted disks (dmg/usb/etc...).

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31953/removing-modem-icon-from-menubar/31958#31958

Comment: I'm inclined to leave this here. The wording is different and one is general and the other specific. Having two or three good questions that are distinct enough in wording will help a greater number of people searching for questions to find an answer here. Unless there are other exact matches, these two questions are fine for the site.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't have found the other question.

Comment: I guess I know what commonly causes this: If you attach a non-Apple keyboard, the Eject menu comes for rescue as a replacement for the missing keyboard Eject key.

Comment: In my experience, this icon only appears when you have a super drive attached.  Remove it, and it goes away.  Is this not happening for you?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and drag it away from the menubar.

Comment: You can also move them. Notice that this does not have to work with every application. e.g. Dropbox does not honor the key, while iStat Menu does it. On the other hand you remove Spotlight search using this trick.

Comment: @bot47 In the future, if you already know it's a duplicate, please `flag` it for moderator attention to have it closed, and don't answer it. There's no point in duplicating information all over the place.

Comment: I did flag and answer it

Comment: Thank you for the flags - in general we do like to close exact duplicates but this is more of a special case. The flags were helpful to make sure we want both questions here.

Comment: I just tried this tip and I can move the icon from left to right but I can't remove it. (using Mavericks 10.9.2).

Comment: Are you using any tools to manipulate the menu bar? Something like Bartender?

Comment: Sir, you made my day !

Answer (score 0):

If you have Bartender installed, use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd> and drag the icon away from the menubar.

Comment: I just tried. Command alone is working. Maybe you have some tweaking tools installed?

Comment: Ooops. True, I have Bartender installed.