# How can I remove the eject button from my menubar when cmd-drag won't work?

Tags: icon, menu-bar, eject

I have an eject icon in my menubar that I cannot remove by command-dragging it out of the bar. Is there a command I can run in Terminal?

Comment: in the actual top menu bar, or do you mean in the Finder window toolbar? [picture would help, if you can't post it directly to your question link it to imgur, flikr etc & someone can inline it for you] The first would have to be some app putting it there, the second is just View menu >Customise toolbar, drag it out.

Comment: Duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40302/how-can-i-remove-the-eject-icon-from-the-menubar

Comment: Kent: This is not a duplicate. I literally cannot drag the object out of my menu bar, which that ticket does not address. Tetsujin: I mean the top menu bar or system tray or whatever you want to call it. Cmd-drag doesn't work. I can remove other objects no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have realized what the problem was

If you use Bartender.app, if the app is active, you cannot drag items out of the menubar. You need to quit Bartender first

Comment: Could you explain a bit more so that the answer would be useful to others who get into this state

Comment: Yes. If you use Bartender.app, if the app is active, you cannot drag items out of the menubar. You need to quit Bartender first.